# What's wrong with this short Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

I'm trying to make the short Javascript code throw an alert and show 93 instead of 0-93 but it's not working ?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function numberFromInput(value) {
  return  alert(Number(value.match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop()));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

numberFromInput(0-93);

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not actually calling your function.  If you want to call it, you need to do that within a `<script>` tag as well.  Otherwise, your `numberFromInput(0-93);` is just a text node on the page.

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript.

Comment: that still doesn't throw the alert

Comment: You're trying to perform `value.match`, but the value you pass is a `Number` (`0 - 93` will evaluate to `-93`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the function (you're just displaying its call code as content). And you have to pass the value as a string (you need quotes around `0-93`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function numberFromInput(value) {
    return alert(Number(value.match(/[-]?(\d*)$/).pop()));
}
numberFromInput("0-93");
</script>
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsbin.com/izalux/1/edit. Are you sure you did include the quotes around the string when you first tried it?